# Failed to reference Azure Function .net library in Visual Studio Resource Group Template

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

If I try to add a reference to a Azure Function .net462 library in my VS 2017 Resource group template, I get the following error:

> ===================== 28/09/2017 09:24:07 LimitedFunctionality System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Could not resolve mscorlib for
>   target framework 'Deployment,Version=v1.0'.  This can happen if the
>   target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is
>   incorrectly formatted.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse..ctor(IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader
>   assemblyLoader, IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution
>   projectAssemblyResolution, IVsSmartOpenScope dispenser)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse.GetUniverse(IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader
>   assemblyLoader, IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution
>   projectAssemblyResolution, IVsSmartOpenScope dispenser)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkProvider..ctor(IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution
>   assemblyResolution, IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader,
>   TypeDescriptionProvider parentProvider, IVsSmartOpenScope openScope)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectUtilities.GetTargetFrameworkProvider(IServiceProvider
>   provider, IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, IVsHierarchy
>   hierarchy, Object instance)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.get_TypeProvider()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.VSLangProj._dispReferencesEvents.ReferenceAdded(Reference
>   r)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAVSReferences.OnReferenceAdded(Reference
>   reference)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ReferencesHostBridge.ApplyAsync(ReferencesDelta
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectHostBridge`3.<>c__DisplayClass36_1.<<InitializeCoreAsync>b__3>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__78.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectHostBridge`3.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<<InitializeCoreAsync>b__2>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework 'Deployment,Version=v1.0'.  This
>   can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the
>   framework moniker is incorrectly formatted.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse..ctor(IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader
>   assemblyLoader, IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution
>   projectAssemblyResolution, IVsSmartOpenScope dispenser)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse.GetUniverse(IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader
>   assemblyLoader, IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution
>   projectAssemblyResolution, IVsSmartOpenScope dispenser)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkProvider..ctor(IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution
>   assemblyResolution, IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader,
>   TypeDescriptionProvider parentProvider, IVsSmartOpenScope openScope)
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectUtilities.GetTargetFrameworkProvider(IServiceProvider
>   provider, IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, IVsHierarchy
>   hierarchy, Object instance)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.get_TypeProvider()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.VSLangProj._dispReferencesEvents.ReferenceAdded(Reference
>   r)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAVSReferences.OnReferenceAdded(Reference
>   reference)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ReferencesHostBridge.ApplyAsync(ReferencesDelta
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectHostBridge`3.<>c__DisplayClass36_1.<b__3>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.d__78.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.<JoinAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectHostBridge`3.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<b__2>d.MoveNext()<---

Was anybody able to build and deploy azure functions .net libraries from an VS Resource Group Template.
I got it working with a .net462 webapp. Therefore I do not understand whats the difference here.

here is my csproj-file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs" Version="1.0.9" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.1.0-beta1" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.2" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />    
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="1.2.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Could you please post your details template?  Which Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version you have used now?  I used 1.0.2, it could successfully add references.

Comment: I fixed the problem by moving my code from azure function to a webjob. I have the same sdk 1.0.2. Updated the details in the question above. Did you use the latest Function tools? I'm was not able to update to the latest function tools becaus installation crashes.